# Fetching images from URL using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uri

I know this has already been asked before but I couldn't find anything quite like the issue I am facing.

I am using the `open()` method to download and save the file.

```
img = Image.new
img.image = open(url)
img.save
```

This throws an error: `Paperclip error while determining content type`
I found this on SO, but I am on a linux machine so it does not apply:

[paperclip Error while determining content type: Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError in Rails 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478940/paperclip-error-while-determining-content-type-cocainecommandnotfounderror-in)

The other way to do this is to use `URI.parse()`. However I faced issues with it earlier, it seems to be working fine now.

Overall the behaviour from either one `open()` or `URI.parse()` has been unpredictable. Sometimes they work sometimes they don't. What is the best one to use in this case and what fail safe strategy can I use?

Comment: do you have require 'open-uri' at the top of your file?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced similar problems with certain file types.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and `file --mime` doesn't always manage to find the file type, for example with .doc files.

I got around this by modifing Paperclip to use `file --mime` where it could, and then fall back to `mimetype` otherwise.

Something like this:

```
module Paperclip
  class FileCommandContentTypeDetector
    private

    def type_from_file_command
      # -- original code --
      # type = begin
        # # On BSDs, `file` doesn't give a result code of 1 if the file doesn't exist.
        # Paperclip.run("file", "-b --mime :file", :file => @filename)
      # rescue Cocaine::CommandLineError => e
        # Paperclip.log("Error while determining content type: #{e}")
        # SENSIBLE_DEFAULT
      # end

      # if type.nil? || type.match(/\(.*?\)/)
        # type = SENSIBLE_DEFAULT
      # end
      # type.split(/[:;\s]+/)[0]

      # -- new code --
      type = begin
        Paperclip.run('file', '-b --mime :file', file: @filename)
      rescue Cocaine::CommandLineError
        ''
      end

      if type.blank?
        type = begin
          Paperclip.run('mimetype', '-b :file', file: @filename)
        rescue Cocaine::CommandLineError
          ''
        end
      end

      if type.blank? || type.match(/\(.*?\)/)
        type = SENSIBLE_DEFAULT
      end
      type.split(/[:;\s]+/)[0]
    end
  end
end
```